# Can't access publicly exposed Docker container port from external machine, only from localhost?

Tags: linux, docker, port, iptables

I have a Docker container running on my Ubuntu Linux 14.04 machine that exposes a port publicly:

```
docker run --name spacyapi -d -p 127.0.0.1:7091:7091 jgontrum/spacyapi:en
```

I can connect and execute commands against the server in the container without problem from the local machine.  For example:

```
curl http://localhost:7091/api --header 'content-type: application/json' --data '{"text": "This is a test."}' -X POST
```

The command executes faithfully.  However, if I try the same CURL command from an external machine I get a "connection refused" error:

```
curl http://192.5.169.50:5000/api --header 'content-type: application/json' --data '{"text": "This is a test."}' -X POST
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.5.169.50 port 7091: Connection refused
```

Where 192.5.169.50 is the IP address of the box running the Docker container.

I don't think I need any iptables rules because I didn't need to set any up for the Node.JS server running on the same box.  All the other computers on my local network can access the Node.JS server just fine.  But not the Docker container acting as a server.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't think the container's IP is 192.5.169.50. Try doing  `docker inspect <container-uid> | grep IPAddress` to check what the IP of the container is.

Comment: @BillCheng - 192.5.169.50 is the IP address of the box running the Docker spaCy container.  I am accessing that box from another box on our Intranet.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You didn't publicly publish your port with this flag:

```
-p 127.0.0.1:7091:7091
```

That flag says to publish on the host 127.0.0.1 interface (localhost), port 7091 to the containers port 7091. The only way to reach that port is to be on the host and connect to the loopback interface.

To publicly publish the port, remove the IP from that flag:

```
-p 7091:7091
```

or explicitly publish to all interfaces with:

```
-p 0.0.0.0:7091:7091
```

The latter format is identical to the first one as long as you haven't overridden your docker daemon settings with `dockerd --ip x.x.x.x` or setting the `ip` value in your /etc/docker/daemon.json file.

Comment: Thanks!  I used the first example you show and now it works..  Can you add to your answer what the effective/actual difference is between using or not using 0.0.0.0 as part of the port assignment command line argument, especially if there are any differences in security or availability between the two formats?

Comment: Docker defaults to using 0.0.0.0 unless you override it with a setting to the `dockerd` daemon, so the two formats are normally identical.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think the container's IP is 192.5.169.50. Try doing  `docker inspect <container-uid> | grep IPAddress` to check what the IP of the container is. I believe it should be something like 172.17.0.X.

Also you could just do `docker run -d --network=host <image>` which stacks the container on top of the host network.

Container are just something on top of the host, the host is the one that is actually communicating with the outside.

Comment: can you elaborate on this statement "which stacks the container on top of the host network" or link me to a document that explains it?

Comment: Here you go: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#default-networks

Comment: thanks for the `--network=host` parameter